# Getting location to show in the console

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to get the latitued and longitude to print to the console, but nothing is showing with the code I have.  It seems to work in JSfiddle, but not on my desktop.

```
function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
    }


  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/gf0gmhqv/

Comment: The code works, maybe it's because sharing location requires permission from the visitor. I get some popup asking me if I want to share my location, when I click allow, the coordinates are printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Like @M4tini said, works fine. Problem is, why doesn't it do that for you?

You can find out with the new permission api (for firefox and blink only) if it is granted, denied or prompt

You can also use the error callback to find out if there where any problem getting the position

```
navigator.permission.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(permission => {
    alert(permission.state)
})

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

function error(err) {
    console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message)
}
```